# Seletor parent css

Tags: css

Existe alguma forma de selecionar usando somente css as imagens cujo o elemento pai é uma `<div class="img-parent" ></div>`, ou seja, **a partir de** um elemento filho?

```
<div class="img-parent" >
   <img src="/teste.png">
</div>
```

Algo como `.img-parent < img`, inverso, onde a img é filha da div?

Comment: `.img-parent img` irá pegar todas as imagens filhas de `.img-parent`. Essa regra não atende?

Comment: Em CSS vc não consegue pegar o elemento pai. Só dá pra fazer isso em jQuery

Answer (score -1):

É só fazer o seguinte: `.img-parent img{ //Estilo do elemento }`